# What does this sentence mean?no CPU power or battery life is wasted drawing animations that are running in background tabs

Tags: cpu, battery, requestanimationframe

context:
   First, it only draws the animations that will be visible to the user. That means no CPU power or battery life is wasted drawing animations that are running in background tabs, minimized windows, or otherwise hidden parts of a page.

My first language is not English, is this sentence means: animations that are running in background tabs, minimized windows, or otherwise hidden parts of a page will not be drawed , so no CPU power or battery life is wasted

Answer (score 1):

It means that the RAF (Request Animation Frame) loop *does not run* when the window cannot be seen and the browser does *not* update the display of such hidden windows.

As a consequence, any animation updates (and other work) that is normally done from within the RAF callback will also be suspended until the window is once again visible and the RAF resumes.

If timed logic must continue a background window the RAF cannot be reliably used because of this optimization.